# A question about chaining Vinogradov notation

Tags: notation

This is *not* a research question, but I hope it is still legitimate to ask for this platform. Suppose $A(x)$, $B(x)$, $C(x)$, $D(x)$ are positive-valued functions of $x$, and
$A(x) \ll B(x)$ and $ C(x) \ll D(x)$, where $ \ll$ is the [Vinogradov symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations)). Suppose, further, that $B(x) \le C(x)$. There are two ways of expressing these chain of "inequalities" in one line:
$$ A(x) \ll B(x) \le C(x) \ll D(x) $$
and
$$ A(x) \ll B(x) \ll C(x) \ll D(x) $$
The first has the advantage of being more precise, while at the same time could be misreading, in that the implied constant in $A(x) \ll C(x)$ might not be taken to be $1$.  Is there a convention for writing such chains of "inequalities"? If so, which one of the two formulations is preferable?

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, the preferable notation is the one that cannot be misinterpreted by the reader. In this case, I'd use $$A(x)\ll B(x)\quad\text{and}\quad B(x)\le C(x)\quad\text{and}\quad C(x)\ll D(x).$$ While maybe a little more to write, it has the advantage of being unambiguous.

Comment: You refer to the implied constant in $A(x) \ll C(x)$, but I think you mean the implied constant in $B(x) \ll C(x)$.

Comment: What I meant was that a reader may simply drop $B(x) $ and deduces that $A(x) \le C(s)$, which, of course, does not have to be the case. I understand that this would be highly unlikely, but I am trying to be on the safe side by considering all possibilities.